# Get all possible dots that form a continuous path - Python

Tags: python, path, point

For example given points: points = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,7),(4,7),(6,7)], i need the program to find all combination such that there's a path between points (let's say 7 is the destination we want to reach)

`so the output would be:  [(1,2),(3,4),(5,7)] [(1,2),(3,4),(4,7)] [(1,2),(3,4),(6,7)]`  
u get the idea?

I'm really stuck with it an i cannot find something similar on the internet.

Comment: how is that ```(3,4) and (5,7)``` is continuous, how ```(3,4) and (4,7)``` is continuous and finally ```(3,4) and (6,7)`` is continuous ??? do you have any graph or something ?

Answer (score 0):

Truly, I don't get why you need this, but it is a simple task.

```
source_list = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,7),(4,7),(6,7)]
final_point = 7 # ??? did not get the logic, btw

def some_magic_shit(lst, fp):
  out = []

  while True:
    way = []
    for k, v in enumerate(lst):
      way.append(v)

      if v[1] >= fp:
        lst.pop(k)
        out.append(way)

        if k >= len(lst):
          return out
        else:
          break

print(some_magic_shit(source_list, final_point)) # [[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 7)], [(1, 2), (3, 4), (4, 7)], [(1, 2), (3, 4), (6, 7)]]
```

The code above should be rewritten with the proper logic.
It only uses **Y axis** as a final point.